# Listing all collections in database and sending them to express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get all of the collections in the database and send them over to the handlebars.
My current code gets me the array of all collections, but I'm not quite sure how to get the name of it

```js
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {

    MongoClient.connect(url).then((client) => {
        const connect = client.db(databasename);
        connect.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collections) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(collections)        
            res.render('index', { title: 'Home', data: collections });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
{{#each data}}
<a href="" class="d-flex">
   <i class="my-auto fa-regular fa-copy"></i>
    <span class="ms-2"> {{ name }}</span> 
</a>
{{/each}}
```

So basically, I need to get the name of all of the collections and have them in .hbs

Answer (score 0):

for getting the name of all of the collections from **MongoDB** you can use

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

To know more about this, you can prefer
MongoDB Documentation click on this link
[enter link description here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getcollectionnames--)